# Error deploying VMWare vCenter Server Appliance

Tags: windows, server, vmware, virtualization

I'm trying to deploy VMWare vCenter Server Appliance.

Mi virtual datacenter looks like:

- 1 x host ESXi (10 GB RAM)

  - Windows Server 2012 Virtual Machine (Primary)
  - Windows Server 2012 (Secondary)
- 1 x host ESXi (4 GB RAM)
- 1 x FreeNAS (Sharing 200 GB HD iSCSI)

I follow this [instructions](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc/GUID-F06BA415-66D8-42CD-9151-701BBBCE8D65.html) to deploy vCenter Server Appliance:

- I've installed a Windows Server VM in mi ESXi host.
- I've mounted the iso image of VMWare vCenter Server Appliance.
- I've clicked the setup file and started the installation.
- I've followed the installation steps for installing vCenter Server Appliance with an Embedded Platform Service Controller.

I've got the followin error during the installation:

Spanish: *error de instalación no se pudieron descargar los registros del paquete de soporte de vcenter*

English: *installation error, vcenter records support package could not be downloaded*

Anyone can tell me what is the meaning of this error? How can I fix it? Other way to install VMware vCenter Server Appliance?

Comment: I strongly suggest install vCenter Server on a Windows Virtual Machine or Physical Server instead vCenter Server Appliance if someone get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

@Kroka VMware Prefer the usage of the Appliance btw... And I do it also...

So back to the Problem:

DNS-Lookup is possible for the vcenter appliance? The Gateway is pingable?

Which version of appliance?

Use another Browser

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi, which version of vCenter appliance? 5.5 / 6 ? The actual version of the vCenter appliance? Have you create DNS-Entrys for the Hostname of the vcenter? Is the IP pingable?

Comment: Finally I installed vCenter Server on a Windows Virtual Machine like I said in the comment. The nslookup was working fine and the gateway was pingable. The appliance version is 6.0.0. @Sven-J